# Limit the domain of a custom function in R

Tags: function, plot

I would like to plot three custom functions using ggplot2 in R. However I would like to set the domains of each function separately.
eg for values of y1 for x=>0.1:

```
y1 <- function(x, x=>0.1) {0.0323488-0.00287746*x-1.33985e-05*x^2}
```

I have attached my code:

```
library(ggplot2)
x<-seq(0,-100, by=-1)
x<-as.data.frame(x)
y1 <- function(x) {0.0323488-0.00287746*x-1.33985e-05*x^2}
y2 <- function(x) {0.0144666-0.00656506*x-2.97314e-05*x^2}
y3 <- function(x) {-0.0584923-0.0124322*x}


#plot multiple functions in a single output
p4a <- ggplot(x, aes(x = x)) + geom_path(aes(colour="red"), stat="function", fun=y1, size = 1)+ geom_path(aes(colour="blue"), stat="function", fun=y2, size = 1) + geom_path(aes(colour="black"), stat="function", fun=y3, size = 1) + xlim(0,-100) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.9)) +  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
    scale_colour_identity("Function", guide="legend", labels = c("y1", "y2", "y3"), breaks = c("red", "blue", "black"))
p4a
```

The problem is the overlap that is occurring in lower ranges of the plots:[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `ifelse`
`xlim` can be used to define the range of the x axis in this particular example, however the method of defining the function domain is what I was after.

```
 library(ggplot2)
    x<-seq(0,-100, by=-1)
    x<-as.data.frame(x)
    
    y1 <- function(x) {ifelse(x>-25,-10, 0.0323488-0.00287746*x-1.33985e-05*x^2)}
    y2 <- function(x) {ifelse(x>-25,-10, 0.0144666-0.00656506*x-2.97314e-05*x^2)}
    y3 <- function(x) {ifelse(x>-25,-10, -0.0584923-0.0124322*x)}
    
    ggplot(x, aes(x = x)) + geom_path(aes(colour="red"), stat="function", 
fun=y1, size = 2)+ geom_path(aes(colour="blue"), stat="function", 
fun=y2, size = 2) + geom_path(aes(colour="black"), stat="function",
fun=y3, size = 2) + xlim(0,-100) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,0.9)) + 
scale_colour_identity("Artery", guide="legend", labels = c("Left Iliac 
Artery", "Both Iliac Arteries", "Abdominal Aorta"), breaks = c("red", 
"blue", "black"))+labs(title="Reflection at the Aortic Trifucation",
 x="Percent narrowing in iliac vessel radius", y="Reflection 
Coefficient")+ theme(text= element_text(size=18))
```

[image]